# Reading password from TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a Password field in C# as

```
 public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox passwordBox;
```

other setting made for this field are

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(381, 199);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "Progpassword";
            this.Text = "Programmer Password";
            this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(192)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(192)))));
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Progpassword_Load);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel1.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();
```

I am not able to read the text entered in the TextBox

I am reading the value using following line

```
string text = PasswordBox.Text;
```

Is this the right way to read the password field.

Comment: How  do you want to read from that textbox?

Comment: @ Likurg I am putting the value into a string field using PassWord.text

Comment: "I am not able to read the text entered in the passwordbox" what does it mean ???

Comment: Maybe your error is that you using PasswordBox.Text - first letter must not be capital... just passwordBox.Text

Comment: when you trying to read that password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `text = passwordBox.Text;` is only that way how you can get it!

Comment: @ Likurg but it is not able to assign the value entered in password field to the text variable